# AQGridView problem when i modify the fetchRequest's predicate

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate, aqgridview

I'm trying to change the fetchRequest's predicate on my NSFetchedResultsController, but when i try to reload the data from the aqgridview, none cell is displayed.

My code:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName: nil];  

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"colection = %@", newcolection ];
[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

[comicGridView reloadData];
```

SOLVED:

OK, solved. I had to change the "setContentSize: (CGSize) newSize" method in AQGridView.m:

From:

```
if (newSize.height < footerHeight + minimumHeight)
```

To:

```
if (newSize.height < minimumHeight)
```

As minimumHeight already contains footerHeight, before, footerHeight is added in twice.

Comment: I think the problem might be in the method reloadData, exactly in self.contentSize = [_gridData sizeForEntireGrid];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved: answer in the question.